# SHA1 hash not accepted by API

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, hash

I'm developing an app that uses a barcode to pull data from an API.

For each call I need to generate a hash value as a signature. Which is a combination of my API ID and the barcode.
I've got an issue where my hashed value is the same each time, therefore my calls are failing.

The functions to create the hash are in objective-C and I have a bridge so I can call it in SwiftUI.

**NSString+SHA1.m**

```
#import "NSString+SHA1.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

@implementation NSString (SHA1)

- (NSString *)hashedValue:(NSString *)key
{
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    
    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    
    NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    //Used to be [HMAC base64Encoding], but is now depreciated
    
    return hash;
}

@end
```

As base64Encoding is depreciated, I tried to use base64EncodedStringWithOptions instead. This may be done incorrectly and could be the cause of why my hash value is the same each time.

This is how I call it in SwiftUI:

```
 let hashedValue = scannedCode.barcode.hashedValue("(API ID)")
```

scannedCode is an observable object that stores the scanned barcode under "barcode" as a String.

In the bridging header:

```
#import "NSString+SHA1.h"
#import "NSString+SHA1.m"
```

**NSString+SHA1.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (SHA1)

- (NSString *)hashedValue:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

EDIT:

I fixed the problem of the hash value being the same, but the API still isn't accepting my signature. So it's to do with the calculation being wrong.

Comment: You'll want `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0` in order to get the same behavior as with `base64Encoding`.

Comment: But please clarify your question. If the problem of the “hash value always being the same” is solved than update the title accordingly. You should show the input data, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @MartinR My bad, I didn't realise you could update the title. The problem is the SHA1 hash with the barcode and my App ID isn't accepted with my API.

Comment: As I said, my guess is that you have to replace `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength` by `0` (zero) for “no options”.

Comment: @MartinR that's correct. Thank you, it's fixed now :)